# Changing routes always displays main component, how can I hide it/remove it from view on specific routes?

Tags: angular

I have the following html template inside my app.component.html file

```
`
<app-layout>
    <mat-sidenav-container>
        <mat-sidenav #sidenav role="navigation">
            <app-sidenav-list (sidenavClose)="sidenav.close()"></app-sidenav-list>
        </mat-sidenav>
        <mat-sidenav-content>
            <app-header (sidenavToggle)="sidenav.toggle()"></app-header>
            <main>
              <router-outlet></router-outlet>
              <app-home></app-home>
            </main>
        </mat-sidenav-content>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
</app-layout>
`
```

My routes configuration module looks as follows

```
`
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeView },
  { path: 'not-found', component: PageNotFoundComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(
    routes, 
    {enableTracing: true}
    )
  ]
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
`
```

Whenever I navigate in the URL to /asdf, I am correctly redirected to not-found route. The page-not-found component's template is rendered at the top of the page above the home component content. I want to hide/remove the Home component content when user types in incorrect URL. How can I achieve this? I tried doing pathMatch: 'full', but that did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove ```<app-home></app-home>``` in app.component.html..

Comment: Yup, that did it. Thanks

Comment: Very helpful, i removed my index page component tag and then i can see the page is changing when i change the route. Thanks :) Just place <router-outlet> inside app.component.ts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in the layout because the `router-oulet` and the `<app-home>` are at the same level.
You have to make sure to change the way you navigate to the pages because all pages generated by navigation will be displayed with your home page.

```
<app-layout>
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav role="navigation">
        <app-sidenav-list (sidenavClose)="sidenav.close()"></app-sidenav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <app-header (sidenavToggle)="sidenav.toggle()"></app-header>
        <main>
          <!-- Its there your problem -->
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
          <app-home></app-home>
        </main>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: I understand now. I didnt need to explicitly say to render <app-home> component, because router-outlet will render that component for me depending on the route. It works now after I had taken out the app-home component. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad it helps you.